# How to make two separate child recyclyerViews scroll in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have two recyclerViews(one scrolls horizontally and the other vertically) inside a LinearLayout.

Now I want them both of them  to scroll together when I scroll down. I tried putting ScrollView around the LinerLayout and it kind of works but the scrolling is not smooth which is I guess is due to inefficient memory usage.

So how can I make both the recyclerViews scroll vertically together.

Comment: please show your recyclerview xml.

Comment: try this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.SmoothScroller.html

Comment: You can check the layout file here @AnchalSingh https://github.com/Sourabhlpu/NewsFeed/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/recycler_view.xml